# jQuery Selector - Tabindex = -1

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to write a jquery selector for an element based on its tabindex?

E.g.

```
<div TabIndex='-1'>jQuery me up baby</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this should be possible:

```
$('div[TabIndex*="-1"]')
```

You can find more documentation about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Comment: That would match any tab index which contained -1 not equaled -1.

Comment: True. But  it's also an option anyway (in some cases) and the question wasn't specified that much.

Comment: i agree. I just wanted to make the OP aware.

Comment: @Dampe isn't it case sensitive ? I think It should be "tabindex" ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  It's just another attribute

```
$('[TabIndex="-1"]').
```